# Jeditable and issue with "select" fields - access & update JSON data dynamically from client side

Tags: jquery, json, jeditable

I am using Jeditable with Zend.

Most of updates, I want to do with Jeditable. So a page shows information and each field is editable using Jeditable. Works very well with "text" fields.

Here is Issue --- It is with drop-down list
I have US Sates drop-down list. Jeditable show is correctly, but since it is a ajax request, two specific problems happen

1) It shows value as ID, and not name. I think, I can handle it from server response to send name instead of ID, but I will like to do it on client side

2) After editing it loses "selected" element. Ideally, it needs to refresh 'selected' element since it has changed. If I refresh page, it will be fine because it will be fresh request, but I will not like to do that. That's the whole idea of Ajax  :-)

Ideally, I want to intercept response from server and  want to access the drop-down list ( JSON data ) and show the label for state ID and dynamically change Json data to change selected value for drop-down list.

So how to access and manipulate Json data on client side from Jeditable

here is my code snippet

```
$('.edit_state').editable('/User/user/updprofile',
{  id   : 'element_id',
       name : 'new_value',  
   data   : '<?php  echo json_encode(array_merge($this->aStateIdOptions, array("selected" => $this->user->state_id))); ?>',
   type   : 'select',
   submit : 'OK',
   indicator :  '<img width=14px height=14px src="/images/ui/ajax-spinner.gif">',
     style     : 'border: 0px',
    onerror: function(settings, original, xhr) {
    original.reset()
    alert(xhr.responseText)
    },
   intercept: function (jsondata) {
     obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsondata);
     alert(obj);
     //alert(data);
     // do something 
     return(obj);
     },
   callback : function(value, settings) {
     console.log(this);
     alert(this);
     console.log(value);
     alert(value);
     console.log(settings);
     alert(settings);
     }    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the jEditable source, as far as I can see based on the source code there is code to set the values for options.

```
var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
```

I think you need to send the information like [CA:California,...].
However there is a code for selected property of option element.

```
/* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */ 
$('select', this).children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] || 
        $(this).text() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

I think you need to send the information like [{CA:California, selected:selected}, {TX:Texas, selected:null} OR {TX:Texas}, ...]
THE SOURCE CODE

```
select: {
    element : function(settings, original) {
        var select = $('<select />');
        $(this).append(select);
        return(select);
    },
    content : function(data, settings, original) {
        /* If it is string assume it is json. */
        if (String == data.constructor) {      
            eval ('var json = ' + data);
        } else {
        /* Otherwise assume it is a hash already. */
            var json = data;
        }
        for (var key in json) {
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ('selected' == key) {
                continue;
            } 
            var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
            $('select', this).append(option);    
        }                    
        /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */ 
        $('select', this).children().each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] || 
                $(this).text() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

},